# apache allowing only localhost by IP returns error 301

Tags: apache

I'm trying just to allow access to a web server from the localhost only. This is a fresh CentOS 7 installation with apache 2.4.6.

I created a basic web:

```
[root@server2 ~]# cat /var/www/html/secret/index.html
my password
[root@server2 ~]#
```

Then, the virtualhost and directory as [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html#host) for apache 2.4+ (192.168.1.10 it's the server IP and I have `192.168.1.10 serverX.example.com` in the `/etc/hosts`):

```
[root@server2 ~]# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/varios.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/secret
    ServerName serverX.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<Directory "/var/www/html/secret">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require ip 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.10
</Directory>
[root@server2 ~]#
```

Everything should work, but:

```
[root@server2 ~]# curl serverX.example.com/secret
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /secret
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
[root@server2 ~]#
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

To make the virtual host accessible to localhost only, you can bind it to the ip address 127.0.0.1.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/secret
    ServerName serverX.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

In `/etc/hosts` you can use `127.0.0.1 serverX.example.com` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It was necesary to add one `/` at the end:

```
curl serverX.example.com/secret/
```

With firefox works fine, but with curl or elinks, no.

Best regards.